Why IAsyncInterceptor is not being called in ASP.NET Core?
I'm trying to use Castle.Core.ASyncInterceptor in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project, but the inteceptor is not being called. I want the interceptor to be called when some method of the service TerminalService is called.
Here is what I have:
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new ProxyGenerator());
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAsyncInterceptor, LoggingInterceptor>();
builder.Services.AddProxiedScoped<ITerminalService, TerminalService>();

The declaration of AddProxiedScoped:
public static void AddProxiedScoped<TInterface, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
     where TInterface : class
     where TImplementation : class, TInterface
 {
     services.AddScoped<TImplementation>();
     services.AddScoped(typeof(TInterface), serviceProvider =>
     {
         var proxyGenerator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProxyGenerator>();
         var actual = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TImplementation>();
         var interceptors = serviceProvider.GetServices<IInterceptor>().ToArray();
         return proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(TInterface), actual, interceptors);
     });
 }

This is the implementation of IAsyncInterceptor:
public class LoggingInterceptor : IAsyncInterceptor
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingInterceptor()
    {
    }

    public void InterceptSynchronous(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();

        _logger.Information("Method response: -> {response}", invocation.ReturnValue);
    }

    public void InterceptAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        _logger = Log.ForContext((invocation.GetType().GetTypeInfo().UnderlyingSystemType));

        invocation.ReturnValue = InternalInterceptAsynchronous(invocation);
    }

    public void InterceptAsynchronous<TResult>(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        _logger = Log.ForContext((invocation.GetType().GetTypeInfo().UnderlyingSystemType));

        invocation.ReturnValue = InternalInterceptAsynchronous<TResult>(invocation);
    }

    private async Task InternalInterceptAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Step 1. Do something prior to invocation.
        invocation.Proceed();
        var task = (Task)invocation.ReturnValue;
        await task;
    }

    private async Task<TResult> InternalInterceptAsynchronous<TResult>(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Step 1. Do something prior to invocation.
        invocation.Proceed();
        var task = (Task<TResult>)invocation.ReturnValue;
        TResult result = await task;

        return result;
    }  
}

I'm calling the method of the service I want to be intercepted from a controller in this way:
 public class MyController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly ITerminalService _terminalService;

     public MyController(ITerminalService terminalService)
     {
         _terminalService = terminalService;
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomethingAsync()
     {
         await _terminalService.SomeMethodAsync();
         return Ok();
     }
 }

What am I doing wrong? The method is called and runs without any error but the interceptor is not being called.

How do you call the method?

Hi @YuningDuan,, I edited my question and answering your question I call the method from a controller and the service TerminalService is injected into the controller

Ok,it was a simple error of mine in AddProxiedScoped
 public static void AddProxiedScoped<TInterface, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
     where TInterface : class
     where TImplementation : class, TInterface
 {
     services.AddScoped<TImplementation>();
     services.AddScoped(typeof(TInterface), serviceProvider =>
     {
         var proxyGenerator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProxyGenerator>();
         var actual = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TImplementation>();
         var interceptors = serviceProvider.GetServices<IAsyncInterceptor>().ToArray(); // <-- I was using incorrect interface IInterceptor
         return proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(TInterface), actual, interceptors);
     });
 }

I was using the interface IInterceptor and the correct one is IAsyncInterceptor
